# Multivariate Gaussian Distribution in particle filter

Tags: c++, opencv, particle-filter

While initialising the particles, i need to add some gaussian noise to it. For example

```
particle.x(i) = rect(1)+mgd(1,1,0,10);
```

here `rect(1)` gives the position, and mgd function is providing the noise

The details about the mgd function are:

- Function `x=mgd(N,d,rmean,covariance)`
- Generates a Multivariate Gaussian Distribution
- Usage `x=mgd(N,d,mu,sigmax)`
- This function generates `N` samples from a d-dimension
  Gaussian distribution

My value of `N` and d are always 1, How can I implement the `mgd` function in opencv c++?

Comment: Maybe have a look at 'related link' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142576/sample-from-multivariate-normal-gaussian-distribution-in-c?rq=1 about your question: is you sigma uniform in all dimensions?

Comment: @Micka Yes, its uniform. Is there simple or inbuilt function, because i m not able to understand anything from the answers in that link

Comment: unfortunately the in-built openCV functions only create univariate values as far as I know and I don't know whether multivariate distribution sampling with uniform sigma can be reduced to multiple univariate distributions... sorry

Comment: @Micka that's not true, you can initialize anything that fits into an `cv::InputArray` with the OpenCV rng functions.. check my answer ;)

Comment: @KeillRandor I thought that would only create d univariate distrubtion values, glad to know it better now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at standard library ["random"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/), it includes methods for different distributions, including [normal distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/).

In the case of uncorrelated variables, you can use independent 1D random number for each dimension (see KeillRandor's answer), otherwise it is not correct. For implementation you can look at MATLAB's code, to do it, type in script editor

> mvnrnd

then right mouse click on just typed command and select open mvrnd in context menu. You'll see the MATLAB code for mvnrnd function.

Comment: can u show a little use of that function according to my problem?thanks'

Comment: If you asking for mvrnd, it is the function you ask. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html

Comment: I was asking for  "normal distribution.", the c++ one

Comment: There is C++ usage example at bottom of page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/

Comment: std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(5.0,2.0);

here 5.0 is the mean? and 2.0 is the covariance?

Comment: no, 0.5 is mean, but 2.0 is standard deviation it is square root of variance. Covariance is multidimantional case of variance in the case of uncorrelated variables it will have nonzero elements only on its diagonal.

Comment: Ups, my mistype, sorry.

Comment: Check here: http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/normal_dataset/normal_dataset.cpp I think it is that you want.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV comes with a nice [Random Number Generator](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=rng#rng) class and also many useful functions. To initialize a d-dimensional vector with random gaussian noise, just do:

```
int d = 10; // dimension
float m = 0, cov = 0.1; // mean and covariance
vector<float> X(d,.0f); // your d-dimensional vector
cv::randn(X,m,cov); // <-
```

Cheers!

Comment: shouldnt the mean value have d dimensions (might be auto-created by openCV though)?